# Execution failed for task ':spring-jcl: compile Kotlin ' happened when trying to build Spring 5.0 source code

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, kotlin, gradlew

when I try to import Spring source code into Intellij idea, I execute the first step just as import-into-idea.md,
1. Precompile `spring-oxm` with `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`;
but exception occurs.
Java version:
java --version
java 10.0.2 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
Exception:
$ ./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava

> Task :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
>   Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
>   Task :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
>   Task :buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
>   Task :buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
>   Task :buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :spring-core:cglibRepackJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :spring-core:objenesisRepackJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :spring-jcl:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':spring-jcl:compileKotlin'.

  > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Prog                                                                                                                                  ram Files\Java\jre-10.0.2' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK,                                                                                                                                   not JRE.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                                                                                   option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date

Comment: I think you need JDK 8 to compile Spring 5.0; it will not work correctly with JDK 10.

Comment: When i switch to JDK 8 ,it works.Thx~bro